# How to make multiple counters using HTML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to create something similar to this:
http://pennystocks.la/internet-in-real-time/

Here is there I am at:
https://jsfiddle.net/t44qsb9d/

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var counter = document.querySelector('#foo');
    var countNum = parseInt(counter.dataset.counter,10);
    setInterval(function() {
        count += countNum;
        jQuery('#foo').html(count);
    }, 1000);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:#359BED;color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;padding:40px;"><div style="padding-left:300px;"><div id="foo" data-counter="11">0</div><span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:40px;">Accounts created</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to update this script to update multiple counters as currently it will only work on a single counter. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: What do you want to count?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t44qsb9d/4/

Now the explanation:

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color:#359BED;color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;padding:40px; class="rowT"">
    <div style="padding-left:300px;">
        <div class="foo" data-counter="11">0</div>
        <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:40px;">Accounts created</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:red;color:#ffffff;font-size:30px;padding:40px; class="rowT"">
    <div style="padding-left:300px;">
        <div class="foo" data-counter="25">0</div>
        <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:40px;">Videos Watched</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of using an ID for "foo", I've changed that to a class since the same ID can be referenced only once on a single HTML page.

**JS**

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {

    $('.foo').each(function() {
        var thisDiv = $(this),
            count = 0;
        var countNum = parseInt($(this).data('counter'),10);
        setInterval(function() {
            count += countNum;
            thisDiv.html(count);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I'm iterating through all counters that have the class `foo`. Then I'm storing that particular counter into a variable called `thisDiv`. Rest of the code is similar to what you already had.

Hope this helps.

### UPDATE

I've moved the declaration of the `count` variable into the loop to limit it's scope.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this answer certainly seems to be most way there. Have you noticed though that the 25 adds the 11 too for the second counter. So for example instead of 25 it will start on 36. This then goes back to the first - looks to me like it's adding up what been added so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is an counter object, you can create as many counter as you want:

```
function MyCounter(startNum, increase, interval, selector){
    this.counterValue = startNum;
    this.container = jQuery(selector);
    this.paused = false;
    this.increase = increase;
    this.interval = interval;
    return this;
}

MyCounter.prototype.start = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.counter = setInterval(function(){
        if(!self.paused){
            self.counterValue += self.increase;
            if(self.container && self.container.html){
                self.container.html(self.counterValue);
            }
        }
    }, self.interval);
}

MyCounter.prototype.pause = function(){
    this.paused = true;
}

MyCounter.prototype.resume = function(){
    this.paused = false;
}

MyCounter.prototype.stop = function(){
    clearInterval(this.counter);
}
```

To use it:

```
var fooCounter = new MyCounter(0, parseInt(counter.dataset.counter,10), 1000, '#foo')
fooCounter.start();
```

to pause and resume it:

```
fooCounter.pause();
fooCounter.resume();
```

to stop it:

```
fooCounter.stop();
```